# Proper way to access store in ngrx/effect

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using Angular 6, ngrx/store, ngrx/effects.
I have an effect that should be triggered when i press "Save" button. I am using `withLatestFrom` there to collect all data what i need for sending it to the server:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
  saveAll$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.Save),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getData1),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getData2),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getData3),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getData4)
    ),
    switchMap(([action, data1, data2, data3, data4]: [ActionType, Data1[], Data2[], Data3[], Data4[]]) => {
       // here is some operations with these data
       return this.apiService.saveData({data1, data2, data3, data4})
    })
)
```

Here is `getData1` selector:

```
export const getData1= createSelector(
  getItems,
  getIndexes,
  (items, indexes) => {
    console.log('HI, I AM getData1');
    return transformItems(items, indexes);
  }
);
```

`getItems`, in turn, return `state.items`. The problem is that `state.items` can be modified in another effect:

```
@Effect()
  handleItemsChanges$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.ChangesInItems),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getItems),
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getUsers),
    ),
    switchMap(([action, items, users]: [ActionType, Item[], User[]]) => {
       console.log('I AM handleItemsChanges');
       const actions = [];
       if (itemsShouldBeUpdated) {
          actions.push(new UpdateData(changes))
       }
    })
)
```

So `getData1` selector gets data from the store depend on another effect named `handleItemsChanges`. `handleItemsChanges` effect is triggered every time something is changed related to the items and recalc it again. 
As a result, in `saveAll` i am getting not actual `state.items`.
What am i doing wrong? May be i should use another operator insted of `withLatestFrom` or what ca be the solution? Thank you

P.S. Btw i am using `withLatestFrom` every time when i want to get some data from the store. Is it correct?

Comment: You can write a single selector which gets you all the data. OR you can send all the data you need as payload.

Comment: You might be look this for solution. https://medium.com/@viestursv/how-to-get-store-state-in-ngrx-effect-fab9e9c8f087

Answer (score 2):

you need to have action `handleItemsChanges` fired before `saveAll` gets fired. One way to do it is to create an effect on `handleItemsChanges` action and trigger the `save` action.

The framework will guarantee the order of execution (`handleItemsChanges` first then `save`), this way the `withLatestFrom` operation will work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've found discussion on ngrx github : https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/467 
Looks like we have 2 ugly variants for accessing store from effects now.